# Spring security remember me - logging out one PC forgets all other persistent logins on other PCs

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, remember-me

Remember-me service definition:

```
  <security:remember-me services-alias="rememberMeService" data-source-ref="dataSource" user-service-ref="userService"/>
```

and my persistent_login table (via hibernate) looks like this :

```
@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 128)
private String username;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 128)
private String series;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 128)
private String token;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Date last_used;
```

How to stop all persistent tokens for one username being deleted when logging out on one computer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to override the [`logout` method](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.java#L151) of `PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices`. Decode the cookie using the [`decodeCookie` method](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/AbstractRememberMeServices.java#L187). The first element of the array returned is the token series which you can use to delete the information for that specific session.

Comment: great thanks; although I guess this is the default behaviour for a good reason.